# How to change migration executing order?

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I have two migrations.

**1. Respectively a view**

```
public function up()
{
    DB::statement("CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myView AS
        SELECT * FROM mytable;
    ");
}
```

**2. And a table alter for adding anew column**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('mytable', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->enum('type', ['bulk', 'online']);
    });
}
```

As you see,

that view uses **`*`** to select all columns. 
But after `php artisan migrate`, the `type` column * (after the view is created)* does not exists in the view.

Any idea how can I handle that?

How can I change/specify the order of migrations order?

Or

how can I re-execute that view migration again when that column was created?

Comment: The order of executing migrations depends on creating file datetime. If you didn't deploy your view migration then you can simply update its datetime to be after table alter migration datetime. If you deployed your code then you should change the datetime in filename and also you should delete view's migration row from migrations table on your live server.